# Data type for rtf characters

Tags: c#, richtextbox

What data type should I use to store rtf codes into database, I got stucked with this. I actually use the rtf characters to be saved in the database but when I retrieve it back it gave those string not those of codes.

Answer (score 3):

[Specification-compliant Rich Text Format text is entirely made up of 7-bit ascii characters.](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/RTF-Spec-1.0.txt), so you can use any of the normal string types.